# Rails Merge params with select

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, railscasts, html-select

I was just looking at Ryan Bates railscast tutorial on [Sortable Table Columns](http://railscasts.com/episodes/228-sortable-table-columns) which with a few modifications becomes ajaxified in one of his later videos([Search, Sort, Paginate with AJAX](http://railscasts.com/episodes/240-search-sort-paginate-with-ajax)). I think his solution worked great, it's clean and it degrades easily.

One problem though was the fact that **he was using tables** for his sorting functionality, whereas **I want to use select inputs instead**.

Currently I have it setup with two select boxes, one for the column and another for the search direction, as well as a link to initiate the ajax request (see below for screenshot).

[image: Desired functionality]

However Ryan Bates had it setup so he had an individual link for each sortable column, whereas I'm only going to have one link. I was wondering if anybody knew of a way to extrapolate on what he had and merge the params with the values on a select box.

This is what I had thus far...

```
<table>
        <tr>
            <th>Sort by</th>
            <th>Order</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <%= select_tag "sort", options_for_select([["Creation Date", "created_at"], ["File Name", "name"], ["Rating", "rating_average"], ["Downloads", "downloads"]]) %>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%= select_tag "direction", options_for_select([["Descending", "desc"], ["Ascending", "asc"]]) %>
            </td>
            <td>
            <%= link_to "Sort", params.merge(:sort => params[:sort], :direction => params[:direction], :page => nil), :class => "icon" %>           
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

If possible I don't want to have to restrict the functionality to only users with JavaScript enabled.

Comment: Where is it that the code is falling down?

Comment: The values selected for both of the select_tags aren't actually being passed along with the link_to, perhaps because those values are set during runtime and the link gets generated server-side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAICS, params from select-tags will come through in pretty much the same way as any other param - so merging them should work the same way. The only difference is that you need to pass `params[:sort]` into the select-tag. Have a look at how you pass in the currently-selected-value here:

http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/select_tag

and

http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/options_for_select

Which suggests a format:

```
<%= select_tag "sort", options_for_select([["Creation Date", "created_at"], ["File Name", "name"], ["Rating", "rating_average"], ["Downloads", "downloads"]], params[:sort]) %>
```

Comment: Hi I appended the suggested params[:sort], but no dice. I believe it's because this doesn't ever actually get set.

Comment: when you click "sort" - what params get sent to your controller?

Comment: Just my authentication token, controller name and action name.

Comment: Ah... You haven't actually got your select_tags inside of a "form_tag"... do that, and change the "link_to" to be a normal submit button, and you should be good to go.

Comment: Ah, maybe I was trying to accomplish something that was overly elegant. See I was looking at this website [Skyrim Nexusmods](http://skyrim.nexusmods.com/mods/searchresults/?cat=95) and noticed that they were doing pretty much exactly what I was trying to accomplish but they weren't using a form. Looking a little closer I see that they're using Javascript which is exactly what I didn't want. I'll settle for the form.

Comment: I've actually ran into a problem with the form submission, perhaps you can take a look at it: [Ajax not sending form params](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11547669/rails-3-ajax-form-not-sending-params)